# PHP: How can I get spl_autoload to work within a class on the global scope?

Tags: php, class, autoload

I'm using spl_autoload for dependency injection.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
    $cFilePath = _CLASSLIB_ . "/class.$class.php";

    if(file_exists($cFilePath))
    {
        include($cFilePath);
    }
    else
    {
        die("Unable to include the $class class.");
    }
});
```

This works fine.  However, let's say these are my classes:

```
class Test 
{ 
   public function foo() 
   { 
      echo "Here."; 
   } 
}
```

And

```
class OtherTest 
{ 
   public function bar() 
   { 
      global $Test; 

      $Test->foo(); 
   } 
}
```

So, in my executing code:

```
<?php
$OT = new OtherTest(); //Dependency Injection works and loads the file.
$OT->bar();
?>
```

I'll get an error because bar() tries to global in the test class (which wasn't instantiated and, thus, never autoloaded).

What is the best way to implement this other than checking to see if the $Test global is an object before trying to use it in every method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using globals if at all possible.  You mentioned Dependency Injection in your comment: You can use DI to solve this issue.

If OtherTest depends on an instance of Test, that instance of Test should be supplied to OtherTest when it is constructed, e.g.

```
$T = new OtherTest($Test);
```

You'd obviously need to amend your OtherTest class to have an instance of Test as a property, and a constructor that takes a Test as an argument, something like:

```
class OtherTest 
{

    protected $test = null;

    public function __construct(Test $test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        return $this->test->foo();
    }

}
```

You could then do the following:

```
$test = new Test();
$otherTest = new OtherTest($test);
$otherTest->bar();
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris!  What I wound up doing is setting up the constructor so I can overload it with an array of the class names and objects as a key/value pair, run it through a switch statement and assign it to the appropriate protected property in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing what is meant by dependency injection.  Class autoloading is not dependency injection. Dependency injection is where you actually inject a dependency that an object might have into the object so that it can work with it.  The object receiving the dependency is thus decoupled from needing to create its dependency at all.

The best way to do achieve dependency injection in this case would be to ACTUALLY inject the dependency on Test class into OtherTest on OtherTest instantiation. So Othertest might look like this:

```
class OtherTest 
{ 
   protected $test_object = NULL;

   public function __construct($test_obj) {
      if ($test_obj instanceof Test === false) {
          throw new Exception('I need a Test object');
      } 
      $this->test_obj = $test_obj;
   }

   public function bar() 
   { 
      $this->$test_obj->foo(); 
   } 
}
```

And the code to instantiate might look like:

```
$OT = new OtherTest(new Test()); // both OtherTest and Test would be autoloaded here if not previously loaded.
```

Note that referring to an undeclared variable (`$Test` in your example) isn't going to autoload a class, as the variable name by itself has no context of a class.  You would just end up getting an error for trying to call a method on a non-object.